# Setting EditText value causes remeasure and layout of UI

Tags: android

I have a fairly complicated UI - lots of views and quite a bit of hierarchy.  I'm working on paring this down, but I've noticed something really strange.

The UI is updated from a backing Model; when the model changes, I recalculate the model in a background thread and then on the UI thread, I pass the updated model around to the various components to redisplay their information.  It takes about 200-300 ms to have the model passed around and for all of the (for example) textview.setText calls to be made.  However the UI doesn't actually update for up to 5 seconds after the update function finishes.

I used the method profiling tool in ddms to see what's going on, and it looks like a ton of measurement and layout calls are being made in the seconds after the update finishes - I overrode onLayout in a few places, and it seems like even setting just one value will cause the entire UI to be remeasured and laid out.

So my question is whether this is normal or not; I can see it taking some time to update, but 5 seconds seems like a long time.  It can take a few seconds to get the UI to show up when the app starts, so I'm wondering if the UI is just too complex.  This is on a Galaxy Tab 10.1 with Android 4.0.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, layout_weight can be very expensive.  The main panel of the application was made up of two instances of the same custom view, split in half using layout_weight:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <CustomView 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <CustomView 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I stuck some timing methods throughout the application and, along with the hierarchyviewer, found that during layout, for each onMeasure call to the linear layout onMeasure was being called 4 times on *each* of the custom views.  Each onMeasure call took about 300-400 ms (as I mentioned, it's a complicated layout), which led to over 3 seconds for the whole view to actually get laid out.

What happens is any time the view changes (say when an edit text has some text added) the widths of the custom views get updated based on the weights.  Since I was only using the weights to set the initial size on the device, and each custom view couldn't adjust its size (since they were both half the width of the screen), I removed the layout_weight attributes on the custom views and added this to the code in onCreate:

```
int halfScreenWidth = ...;
for(View v : new View[]{customViewA, customViewB})
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = halfScreenWidth;
    v.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

This change reduced the number of onMeasure calls to each custom view from 4 to 2, a significant savings.  So the lesson learned here is if the views don't really need to be resizeable at run time, it's better to calculate the width in code rather than relying on layout_weight in XML.